# Table with SERIAL field gets indexes automatically in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a database and I need to add indexes to it.

I have a table like this.

```
    CREATE TABLE Customers
(
    Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName CHARACTER VARYING(30),
    LastName CHARACTER VARYING(30),
    Email CHARACTER VARYING(30),
    Age INTEGER
);


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX customers_idx ON Customers (Id);
```

Do I need to add indexes to it if there is a field with the SERIAL attribute?

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS),

> Adding a primary key will automatically create a unique B-tree index on the column or group of columns listed in the primary key, and will force the column(s) to be marked NOT NULL.

So no, in this case you do not need to create the `customers_idx` yourself, because you defined that column as a primary key. However, the `serial` type itself (if the column isn't a primary key or unique) does NOT automatically come with an index.